# Как создать комплексный словарь из двумернрго списка python

Tags: python-3.x, словари, dict

Есть список заголовков и список списков данных

```
title =['title1', 'title2', 'title3']

D = [[108c, 50,44,35], 
         [108c, None,40,30], 
         [108c, None, 41,39], 
         [102c, 60,55,67], 
         [102c, None, 53,69]
         ]
```

Нужно получить словарь следующего вида

```
new_dict = {  " 108c": {
          "title1": " 50", 
          "title2":[44, 40,41], 
          "title3":[35, 30,39]
                       }, 
  "102c":{
          "title1": "60", 
          "title2":[55, 53], 
          "title3":[67, 69]
                       }
                       }
```

Не понимаю, как такое можно осуществить, только недавно изучаю python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Непонятно, что такое 108с, 102с. Если это строки, то они же в кавычках должны быть. И еще не совсем понятна логика превращения чисел в строки. Если число одно в выходном списке, то оно должно стать строкой? Если это что-то другое - поясните. Пока предлагаю решение для ситуации, когда ключи - это строки, а числа не превращаются в строки, а остаются списком с одном элементом:

```
title =['title1', 'title2', 'title3']

D = [['108c', 50,44,35],
         ['108c', None,40,30],
         ['108c', None, 41,39],
         ['102c', 60,55,67],
         ['102c', None, 53,69]
         ]

new_dict = {k: {title[i]:[d[i+1] for d in D if d[0] == k and d[i+1] is not None] for i in range(len(title))} for k in {k[0] for k in D}}

print(new_dict)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это именно, то что мне нужно!